# I want to change Age column yearly and a dropdown menu for Gender

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2014

Hello I want to change the Gender column into dropdown menu and Age column to change yearly.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Patient
  (
  PatientID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  LabControlID AS Cast(Right(Year(getDate()),4) as varchar(4)) +'-' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(PatientID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5),
  First_Name varchar(50)
  ,Last_Name varchar(50)
  ,Age int
  ,Male bit
  ,Female bit
  )
```

Comment: How will anything ever know if/when the Age has been incremented?  Calculated fields are not usually saved *because* the can be calculated and you can never tell if the saved value is up to date. Sabe the DateOfBirth (as a date).  For gender make it a Text(1) column with a constraint to a table with just MF in it.  The menu can come from the domain table

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Why don't you tell us what you've tried yourself to get that working for you (even if it's not working). Then we can help you make it work properly

Comment: Your question has an **offensive tone** to it. ***"I want this!"*** is not a good way to form your post. Edit your post to include a specific coding question, one that we can base our answers around. Welcome to S/O.

Comment: Also your table design breaks when you have to enter data on a patient that is neither male not female. I have worked in various law enforcement agencies and they typically recognize 6 genders 1) male 2) female 3) trans-gender male 4) trans-gender female 5) hermaphrodite 6) unknown. That information should be stored in a single column with a possible value for each gender.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague.  If you are doing this in ASP.NET C#, it would look something like the following:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMyControl" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Age" DataValueField="PatientID" ></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_Patient]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The  control is a control that you can use to populate data from your database.  Keep in mind if you are going to populate a Drop-Down List, you can do it in a variety of different ways.  This example shows how to do it from markup.

To do the same thing from the Code Behind, the logic is as follows (assuming you have already created the control on your markup page):

1. Create and set the connection of the control (ddlMyControl assuming you set the ID already on the markup page).
2. Set the DataSource of the control.
3. DataBind the control to the page.

This would be something as follows: (C# and VB below)

```
string tableNameSpace = "MyDataSet"; //represents the namespace for the dataset
string queryText = "SELECT * FROM [tbl_Patient]";
string connectionString = "My Connection String Details";
//string tableName = "MyDataTable";//if you were adding tables on the fly, you would use this
DataSet ds = new DataSet(tableNameSpace);

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, connection);//this can also be enclosed in a using statement as well.  See MSDN documentation for more info.
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, connection);            

            dataAdapter.Fill(ds); //fills the dataset with data from your query

            //access the table from your dataset.  
            //If you are returning multiple tables, this is not 
            //going to work correctly.  You'll need to know 
            //what the tables are called.  I would suggest here
            //creating a strongly-typed dataset so you can 
            //reference them by name instead of index.

            ddlMyControl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            //We grab the age to show in the control
            ddlMyControl.DataTextField = "Age";
            //To access the control and reference it through
            //code, you can do something like:
            //ddlMyControl.SelectedValue and that would return the 
            //PatientID. 
            ddlMyControl.DataValueField = "PatientID";
            ddlMyControl.DataBind();
        }
```

VB.NET:

```
    Dim tableNameSpace As String = "MyDataSet"
    Dim queryText As String = "SELECT * FROM [tbl_Patient]"
    Dim connectionString As String = "My Connection String Details"
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet(tableNameSpace)

    'Enclose in a using block to properly dispose resources
    Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(queryText, connection) 'Like my post for C# says, this can also be enclosed in a using block.
        Dim dataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, connectionString)
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds)

            ddlMyControl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]
        '    We grab the age to show in the control
        ddlMyControl.DataTextField = "Age"
        '    To access the control and reference it through
        '    code, you can do something like:
        '    ddlMyControl.SelectedValue and that would return the 
        '    PatientID. 
        ddlMyControl.DataValueField = "PatientID"
        ddlMyControl.DataBind()

    End Using
```

Setting the connection and datasource is a post in and of itself.

There's more to it than what is listed here, but this is the basic idea of how to accomplish what you want.